# How can write text if option selected?

Tags: html

Hello everyone I'm trying to do when a user select one of option , user can see a text.

For example : If user select Mercedes user can see text like "Mercedes is the best German car"

```
<body>

<select>
  <option>Volvo</option>
  <option selected="selected">Saab</option>
  <option>Mercedes</option>
  <option>Audi</option>
</select>

</body>
```

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to achieve a little more - where do you want the text to appear? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Teodoris: See my answer below with a better implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will alert the selected text. Try this:

```
<body>
<select id="we">
  <option>Volvo</option>
  <option selected="selected">Saab</option>
  <option>Mercedes</option>
  <option>Audi</option>
</select>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var a=document.getElementById( 'we' );
    alert(a.options[a.selectedIndex].text)
</script>
</body>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Hi you can do this using JavaScript

Make a change in the your code :

**HTML :**

```
<body>
<select name="type" id="type" onchange="call(this.value);">
  <option>Volvo</option>
  <option selected="selected">Saab</option>
  <option>Mercedes</option>
  <option>Audi</option>
</select>
<div id="message"></div>
</body>
```

**SCRIPT :**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function call(value){
      var x=document.getElementById("message");
      x.innerHTML = value+" is the best German Car";
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="carMessage"></div>
        <select id="cars">
          <option>Volvo</option>
          <option selected="selected">Saab</option>
          <option>Mercedes</option>
          <option>Audi</option>
        </select>

        <script>
            $('#cars').change(function() {
                var msg = $('#cars').text() + " are the best cars.";
                $('#carMessage').text(msg);
            });
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

See this example, In this while selecting different options it will get value and title of selected option and write it in a destination div.

**HTML:**

```
<select name="type" id="selectBox" onchange="call(this.value)">
    <option title="your text for Volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option title="your text for Saab" selected="selected">Saab</option>
    <option title="your text for Mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option title="your text for Audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<div id="message"></div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function call(value){

    var msgDiv = document.getElementById("message");
    var selectBox = document.getElementById("selectBox"); 
    var title = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].getAttribute('title');     
    var message = value + " " + title;      

    msgDiv.innerHTML = message;

}
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/DZuDH/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using javascript. Follow [**these tutorials**](http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/select.shtml)